# spaCy on PySpark and Dataproc: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, spacy-3

[I was dealing with a previous error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73559331/16706763) when trying to perform some Named Entity Recognition with spaCy, relying on Dataproc + PySpark. I have created a brand-new cluster, to deal with "insufficient local disk space", as mentioned in the comments of that case:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create spacy_tests \
--autoscaling-policy policy-dbeb \
--enable-component-gateway \
--region us-central1 \
--zone us-central1-c \
--master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--master-boot-disk-size 500 \
--num-workers 2 \
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--worker-boot-disk-size 500 \
--num-secondary-workers 2 \
--secondary-worker-boot-disk-size 500 \
--num-secondary-worker-local-ssds 0 \
--image-version 1.5-debian10 \
--properties dataproc:pip.packages=spacy==3.2.1,numpy==1.19.5,dataproc:efm.spark.shuffle=primary-worker \
--optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER,DOCKER \
--project mentor-pilot-project
```

Nevertheless, I have stumbled upon a new error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9a88da6b7731> in <module>
     39 
     40 # loading spaCy model and broadcasting it
---> 41 broadcasted_nlp = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(load_spacy_model())
     42 
     43 print("DATA READING (OR MANUAL DATA GENERATION)...")

<ipython-input-1-9a88da6b7731> in load_spacy_model()
     20 
     21 def load_spacy_model():
---> 22     import spacy
     23     print("\tLoading spacy model...")
     24     return spacy.load("./spacy_model")  # This model exists locally

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in <module>
      9 
     10 # These are imported as part of the API
---> 11 from thinc.api import prefer_gpu, require_gpu, require_cpu  # noqa: F401
     12 from thinc.api import Config
     13 

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/api.py in <module>
      1 from .config import Config, registry, ConfigValidationError
----> 2 from .initializers import normal_init, uniform_init, glorot_uniform_init, zero_init
      3 from .initializers import configure_normal_init
      4 from .loss import CategoricalCrossentropy, L2Distance, CosineDistance
      5 from .loss import SequenceCategoricalCrossentropy

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/initializers.py in <module>
      2 import numpy
      3 
----> 4 from .backends import Ops
      5 from .config import registry
      6 from .types import FloatsXd, Shape

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/backends/__init__.py in <module>
      6 
      7 from .ops import Ops
----> 8 from .cupy_ops import CupyOps, has_cupy
      9 from .numpy_ops import NumpyOps
     10 from ._cupy_allocators import cupy_tensorflow_allocator, cupy_pytorch_allocator

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/backends/cupy_ops.py in <module>
     17 from .. import registry
     18 from .ops import Ops
---> 19 from .numpy_ops import NumpyOps
     20 from . import _custom_kernels
     21 from ..types import DeviceTypes

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/backends/numpy_ops.pyx in init thinc.backends.numpy_ops()

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

The `ValueError` I am getting is most likely related with *"the package sources being different"* ([quote](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5270#issuecomment-798905994)) but I am not sure if that applies also for my case (In summary and after googling that error, it seems to go away by *"uninstalling **certain** package, and installing it again"* or *"upgrading **certain** package"*; needless to say, I don't know **which package** would apply for my case, if any). Nevertheless, I would like to stress the fact that *"the default cluster packages shipped with Dataproc* (so to speak) *cannot be controlled from my side"* (or so I think)

**NOTES:**

- I have tried to insert the results of `pip list` and `conda list`, howevere they were too lenghty; if you need some specific package version, please leave the command in the comment section. Leave another requests there too, I will make sure to be updating this section.

What can be happening here?